# Create Link for redirect [ControllerBasic]/{id}/[SecondController]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I want to create link for one request and i cant do this

How can i redirect this:

```
<a asp-controller="@item.Id/Test">@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name, "StringVisible")</a>
```

to this schema: [ControllerBasic]/{id}/Test

Test is Second controller with default action index

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i've done like this

asp-areas="ControllerBasic" asp-controller="@item.Id" asp-action="SecondController"

Comment: That's wrong. Did you [check the docs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-action-tag-helper) ? The `asp-controller`, `asp-action` and `asp-route` attributes aren't replacements for `href`, they're used to construct the link from the controller *name*, action *name* and route attribute values. You should be using `asp-controller='Test' asp-route-id='@item.Id'`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).